# Running function on first time page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to run a spinner on the first time a user views the homepage on a website. I'm using `localStorage` to see if the user has visited the site before but I don't think it is running correctly.

```
function load() {
    var isFired = localStorage.getItem('checkFired');
    if (isFired != '1'){
    } else {
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("fast");
        localStorage.setItem('checkFired', '1');
    }
}

$(window).load(function() {
  load();
});
```

This only needs to run the first time the view the homepage. If they navigate away and come back I don't want the spinner to be displayed. Currently it runs everytime they view the homepage. If I put the below code in the `if` part of the `if` statement, the spinner continues to spin and the page never loads.

```
$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("fast");
localStorage.setItem('checkFired', '1');
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?

EDIT: Css of spinner

```
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(../img/ring.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What's the CSS of your spinner?

Comment: Ahh, so it's always visible by default. You have two choices/issues: 1. make it firstly visible in CSS - wait for DOM ready and fadeOut with JS (spinner will sometimes be visible for Nms). 2. make spinner `display:none;` by default and show it only one first page visit. (issue is now that on page load there will be no spinner for Nms - before JS reads loc.storage and shows it)...

Comment: change `$(window).load(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {` it's odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices (both with it's minor problems)

1. make the spinner CSS ***visible*** by default (and handle *hide* with JS) (like you do already)
2. make the spinner CSS ***hidden*** by default (and handle *show* with JS)

which one you'll use depends on the amount of elements in the DOM (how fast DOM will be ready for JS to trigger (read LStorage, build the DOM nodes etc...))

### Spinner initially `display:block;`

```js
var firstVisit = localStorage.firstVisit != "1"; // Get & store current state (null/"1")
localStorage.firstVisit = "1";  // Page is now visited so set to "1" regardless

jQuery(function($) {

  var $spinner = $("#spinner"); // Use rather an ID. It's faster!
  $spinner.css({display: firstVisit ? "block" : "none"}); // Hide spin. if not first visit

  if( firstVisit ) {            // First time on page
    $(window).load(function() { // P.S: does not applies to unloaded images and media
      $spinner.fadeOut();       // fade out and display none
    });
  }

});
```

### Spinner initially `display:none;`

```js
var firstVisit = localStorage.firstVisit != "1"; // Get & store current state (null/"1")
localStorage.firstVisit = "1";        // Page is now visited so set to "1" regardless

jQuery(function($) {

  if( firstVisit ) {                  // First time on page
    var $spinner = $("#spinner");     // Use rather an ID. It's faster!
    $spinner.css({display: "block"}); // Show spinner

    $(window).load(function() { // P.S: does not applies to unloaded images and media
      $spinner.fadeOut();       // fade out and display none
    });
  }
  // else: spinner will be hidden by default (CSS) so all fine

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i need to use the first as my page half loads then the spinner starts running half way through load as it is a large page. The first one still displays the spinner every time the home page is viewed rather than just the first. any ideas? When i check the local storage after the page loads it does set the value to 1

Comment: @AlexMurray the first example works perfectly fine: http://jsbin.com/virali/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks got it working! for some reason it wasn't working locally but when i pushed up to a server it worked fine. Cheers!

Comment: @AlexMurray glad to hear that! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct but not your logic: Your checking if `isFired` is `not equal to` `1` but you should be checking if `isFired` is equal to `1` because that what the value of isFired is when local storage is set

try:

```
if (isFired == '1')
```

instead of

```
if (isFired != '1')
```

So your code should be just no need of else:

```
function load() {
    var isFired = localStorage.getItem('checkFired');
    if (isFired != '1'){
        localStorage.setItem('checkFired', '1');
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("fast");
    } 
}

$(window).load(function() {
  load();
});
```

**EDIT** As @RococBuljan said..there's a problem with your css as well so try this.

Add `dispaly:block` to your spinner css and do:

```
function load() {
    var isFired = localStorage.getItem('checkFired');console.log(isFired,'aaa')
    if (isFired != '1'){
        localStorage.setItem('checkFired', '1');
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("fast");
    }
    else{
        $(".se-pre-con").css("display","none");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  load();
});
```

Comment: still keeps spinning with this

Comment: don't put anything in `if` block

Comment: Don't forget to clear local storage if the value's been set earlier somehow otherwise that may mess with expected results

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well the data is supposed to persist beyond multiple sessions, so local storage seems like the correct place to put this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to check the var **isFired** or **localStorage.getItem('checkFired');** before any value is assigned, which will always output *null*, hence running the code indefinitely.

Make sure you're adding `localStorage.setItem('checkFired', '1');` in the end of the if statement and try to print the **isFired** when the user enter the page with `window.alert(localStorage.getItem('checkFired'));`
 in order to debug and see if everything is behaving properly.

Comment: null isn't equal to -1 so it doesn't run indefinitely.